# Possible spam notice repeated in question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam

When this note appears on an answer in the review queue "Our system has identified this post as possible spam", it is also repeated in the question. Looks strange, because the question is not being reviewed and the question does not have any suspicious / spam links. A bug or by design due to performance impacts?

> [image]

Comment: Was that an audit? Can you link to the review?

Comment: probably this was one of those cases where someone setup a question in conjunction with the person who answered it so both parts got spam flagged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639584/magento-maximum-discount-restrcition-on-cart/33512842#33512842 is the question, which has never been spam flagged so that kills my guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10304461 is your audit which still looks as in the screenshot on my view.

Comment: But it didn't do it in this earlier audit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10165817 or http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10098234  - maybe some other activity between the two audits caused the question to look spammy for some reason.

Comment: one more case: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/10343927

Comment: @EdCottrell sorry for the delay, yes its an audit. Flexo has posted the correct link above.

Comment: @Flexo were you able to find an audit in which the spam note was displayed only on the answer (and not on question)?

Comment: @AzizShaikh Well, I don't have an answer either, other than that audits do some strange things.

Comment: It looks like status-bydesign to me. The post matches `(discount|commerce)`, a regex which spam posts are likely to match.